# wordpress automatic URL 'page' parameter rewrite

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect, parameter

I have noticed that on my wordpress installation the page

```
domain.com/test?page=2
```

is redirecting to

```
domain.com/test/2
```

I tried disabling all plugins and also used the default/different themes and the behavior exists nevertheless, why I am assuming that this is a wordpress behavior.

Is there any chance to prevent this redirect and keep the ?page parameter intact in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you need to keep the ?page= in the url?  If you just need to get the value of the page you can use:

```
// will return value after "paged" pages "test/page/2" $paged will be 2
$paged = get_query_var('page');
```